# Close jQuery dialog on custom button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using dialog box from link [jQuery Confirm](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/)

```
$.dialog({
    title: '',
    content:'test' ,
    animation: 'scale',
    boxWidth: '50%',
    useBootstrap : false
});
```

**Now I want to close it on button click. There are three custom button on which I perform different functionality on each and then want to close dialog box. So on each button I call onclik function in which some task is done. and then I want to close dialog box**

```
<button onclick="update_details(some parameters);">Close</button>

function update_details(parameters)
{
   // task here depend on parameters  
   // Close dialog box here
}
```

This button is inside dialog box. I tried possible solutions I found here but not working. I hide it using class. but then I can not reopen it. also tried to call close on $dialog

Update :

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  cache:false,
  async:false,
  url: 'url here',
  data:{ },
  success:function(resp){   
    if(resp!='')
    {
        for(var i =0; i < somelenghth from resp; i++)
        {
            str = str + '<button onclick="update_details(parameters);" class="btn btn-default">name</button><br><br>';
        }           

        $.dialog({
              title: '',
              content:str ,
              animation: 'scale',
              boxWidth: '50%',
              useBootstrap : false
          });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Please show us which "possible solutions" you tried and why they failed.

Comment: The docs explicitly state for `.dialog()`: " removes buttons and explicitly shows the closeIcon (×) " - are you sure you don't want to use `.confirm()` instead?

Comment: Connum : Updated question

Comment: I still don't see where you try to implement the close button functionality.

Comment: The link to jQuery Confirm you added contains the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Read documentation, it has very clear answer (hint: Api section).

Comment: ok. I updated question . In bold you can see what is updated.

Comment: I already read docs has mentioned close function but I am not getting how I can call it now

Comment: Yes, close method. Post your code first with buttons how you use them, at the moment you don't have any buttons in content.

Comment: ok I updated how onclick calls function. In that function I want to close dialog

Comment: You still not showing how you use this button, it's not part of dialog.

Comment: I updated question. Depend on response buttons are generated dynamically. and shown in dialog

Answer (score 0):

If you put the content of your dialog inside  tags and assign an ID to it then you will be able to reference it from external functions. Also, you may want to add the close event to destroy the dialog every time is closed.

```
var closedFunction = function() {
    $(#dialogDiv).dialog( "destroy" );
};

$(#dialogDiv).dialog({
    title: '',
    close: closedFunction,
    content:'test' ,
    animation: 'scale',
    boxWidth: '50%',
    useBootstrap : false
});
```

So, having the dialog content referenced by ID you can include this in your button code to close it.

```
<button onclick="update_details(some parameters);">Close</button>

function update_details(parameters)
{
    $(#dialogDiv).dialog( "close" );
    // task here depend on parameters  
}
```

Hope this helps you